# How send multiple HTTP Responses with Intervals from the Server using Python

Tags: python, http, client-server, openshift

Is there a way I can send multiple HTTP responses to a client, once a connection is open? For an instance, suppose it's a game server written in Python running on a PaaS like OpenShift. And a client sends a 'GET' request with the connect request in it. And I want to be able to send 'Updates' from the server once a second to the client. I tried keeping the connection open and writing to the client and it didn't work. All I could do is the client could send a 'request for updates' every second and the server could respond to that. 
Is there a workaround for this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are describing is a websocket, which is a persistent connection between the server and the client. I would recommend you use [socket.io](http://socket.io), because if websockets are not supported by your users browser, then it falls back to other protocols that will serve the same purpose.

In order to use sockets or socket.io, you will have to use a python library on the server that supports them, as well as a library that supports coroutines like gevent or tornado. Check out something like [gevent-socketio](https://github.com/abourget/gevent-socketio) (although it hasn't been updated in a while), or search on pip, `pip search socketio` for some other options.

If you would rather not implement your own solution, another option is to use a messaging service like [Pubnub](http://pubnub.com) or [Pusher](http://pusher.com). I am using Pubnub on my own python+openshift application, and the integration is a breeze. These messaging services take care of maintaining persistent connections with the clients, and when you want to update one client or many clients at a time, you just send a single message to the messaging service and they convey the message to the intended recipients.

Comment: Is there a websocket implementation in Python which I can download through PIP? I searched the web but I couldn't find anything in particular.

Comment: try `pip search socket` to find all of the websocket libraries on pip, or `pip search socketio` for all of the socket.io specific implementations. gevent-socketio is available on pip as well.

Comment: Are there any good PaaS for a custom application such as a game server? I will look into what you said. Thank you.

Comment: That I can't answer, as I have never tried to make a game myself. I would assume the biggest requirement is the ability to support websockets/persistent connections, but that is more the onus of the web framework that you use. Good luck!

Comment: I have tried pubnub on openshift. Although , I have had to shift to java. Thanks a lot for pointing me in the direction. However, I was curious, do you know which port pubnub binds it self to (if any) and how it can be changed to 8080?

Comment: I'm not sure about that either, sorry. The server doesn't need to listen to messages in my case - it just sends them. They have great customer service in my experience, so I would recommend asking them. They might be able to help you better. Good luck!

Comment: well, @Patch Rick Walsh, I'm sure if it works one way it has to work the other way as well. I'll try. Anyways, thanks for the help.

Comment: Ah sorry, what I meant is that when I need to send a message from the server, it just makes a regular post request to the Pubnub server. That's all.

Answer (score 0):

For other people seeing this question, you are describing 1 way communication, another approach rather than websockets would be **Server Sent Events**, the HTTP solution for sending information to the client without changing the protocol (like a websocket would do) you can read a comparative between both options in [this article](https://blog.stanko.io/do-you-really-need-websockets-343aed40aa9b).

Also here is [an article](https://medium.com/code-zen/python-generator-and-html-server-sent-events-3cdf14140e56) about how you can implement them in Python.

Comment: While providing links is useful, it would be MORE helpful to the asker if you posted a summary of the steps involved on the link you posted. For more tips, see [How to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer).